# Change Azure VM Time (not timezone) running Windows Server 2022

Tags: azure, time, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server

I would like to change an Azure server's local time to a month ago. This is for testing purposes on a custom application. Happy if it changes back after reboot.

There are a number of similar posts with answers, but most either refer to changing the timezone, or are old(ish) posts whose answers are not valid anymore. Not sure if Microsoft has made some changes.

What I have tried to to stop the Hyper-V Time Synchronization service as well as the Windows Time service, but to no avail. I also wrote a small c# program to try and do this, but no success.

Anything else that might work?

[image]

Comment: You can refer to similar issues [change time grayed out in windows server](https://serverfault.com/questions/916067/change-time-grayed-out-in-windows-server-2016) and [Windows Server 2016, 2019, 2022, Windows 10 and Windows 11: Date and time "Some settings are managed by your organization".](https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2017/05/windows-server-2016-or-windows-10-date.html)

Comment: Well, well, well. Thanks for the links. The first link actually solved my issue. Open the Local Server section of the Server Manager. @DeepDave-MT, welcome to put as answer and you can get the credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [DeepDave-MT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15969115/deepdave-mt) . Posting your recommendation into answer section as per [Cameron Castillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1208908/cameron-castillo) confirmation. This would help other community members.

Steps to change time settings in Local Server section of the Server Manager:

1. Open the time and date settings in the Local Server section of the Server Manager.
   [image]
2. from the opened time manager window, make the required changes.

Comment: This is not a programming problem, nor a tool or  solution for a tool that solves s programming problem. The question and answer are invalid